# Will a PC keep a WCF service open after restart if not shut down correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, tcp

We are seeing an issue with a WPF application that opens a WCF service that listens to accept data on a port. We had a shortcut that would automatically start this WPF on startup and it worked fine, but we have started restarting the PC through RDP and now when the computer restarts, we get a TCP error in the WPF "The Requested address is not valid in its context" while listening on the correct IP. When we close out of the app and open it back up, it works fine. Is it possible that when we restart without closing this application, it does not quit this connection so on startup when it tries to open this application and start a new service, there is a conflict? I'm new to WCF services and don't know a lot about the inner workings like this, but it seems to me like when we get this error then close out the app we are correctly shutting down this service as well so there is no conflict when we start again.

EDIT: The answer was that networking was not up yet when the app was started. We added a 10 second delay in the batch file to allow for networking to start before running the app:
`choice /C X /T 10 /D X > nul`

Comment: perhaps the network isn't ready when the app comes back up?

Answer (score 1):

With each new Windows version the user can earlier interact with his session but not everything has completely started up. That makes you feel the new system is much more faster than the old as it really is.

Applications that will run on session startup will have to deal with that when the session starts right after a system restart.

So check the system state before starting the service or just retry starting the service until it gets up.